# Getting just a string from a list

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, jsonpath

How do I just get 1 output from "labels"?

tried doing -o=jsonpath='{.metadata.labels[0]}' in hopes of getting the first string but that threw an error.

```
 "metadata": {
        "labels": {
            "beta.kubernetes.io/arch": "amd64",
            "beta.kubernetes.io/os": "linux",
            "kubernetes.io/arch": "amd64",
            "kubernetes.io/hostname": "143.110.156.190",
            "kubernetes.io/os": "linux",
            "node-role.kubernetes.io/controlplane": "true",
            "node-role.kubernetes.io/etcd": "true",
            "node-role.kubernetes.io/worker": "true"
        },
```

Comment: why do you want to fetch the `1st` string ? why not you fetch by name ?

Comment: It's just an example. I'm learning how JSONPATH works with kubectl. And was wondering if I could just get one string instead of all the strings.

Comment: in this particular problem, its better to fetch by name as input is not an array for indexing. also, for learning it make sense, but in real world this problem does not make any sense.

Comment: Yes! Was going to say that the order of the entries is not guaranteed and may change, but if it's just for learning then why not!

Comment: $.metadata.labels['beta.kubernetes.io/arch'] is the only option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

metadata.labels is not an array, so don't think '{.metadata.labels[0]}' will work.

One of the option is perhaps you can try is to use shell to fetch the first value as following:

```sh
kubectl get ingress -o json | jq '.items[0].metadata.labels' | head -2 |tr -d , |cat - <(echo "}") | jq
```

Comment: That works, thanks. But I was hoping for a JSONPATH format. Just wondering if it was possible for a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Kubectl uses JSONPath expressions to filter on specific fields in the JSON object and format the output:

```
kubectl get ingress -o=jsonpath='{.items[0].metadata.labels}'
```

For reference use the following link:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/jsonpath/

Comment: OP has tried doing this. See the first line of the post. OP is looking for the first label, not all of them, and wants to know if this can be done using JSONPATH